# When to create and delete PayPal WebProfile object (PHP)

Tags: php, paypal

I'm using PayPal REST API WebProfile class to customize how a PayPal site should be opened to a customer. There are some things that are not clear for me. Based on PayPal recommendations, I create a WebProfile object, get unique experience_profile_id and use it when creating a Payment object (which opens PayPal site for payment).
Snippets (a lot of code including try blocks, etc. removed for brevity):

```
$my_web_profile = new WebProfile();
$create_profile_response = $my_web_profile->create($my_paypal);
$my_web_profile_id = $create_profile_response->getId();
$my_payment = new Payment();
$my_payment->setExperienceProfileId($my_web_profile_id);
$my_payment->create($my_paypal);
```

All of this works fine.

My questions:

WebProfile class gives a way to update a created web-profile object and delete it. When should I use update and delete methods?
What is the appropriate time to create WebProfile object? Can it be created when a website starts and just reused for every payment customers try to make? Or should it be created for each payment ( when a customer presses "Buy" button ) and deleted after each payment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PayPal API Reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payment-experience/?mark=profile) states:

> As a merchant, you can use the Payment Experience API to create web
>   experience profiles to customize payment flow experiences. You can
>   create multiple product-agnostic web experience profiles. These
>   profiles are decoupled from the core Payments API and your general
>   merchant profile settings and preferences, which enables you to use
>   them across products and integration types.
>
> When you create a payment, you can reference a web experience profile
>   that provides your customers with a seamless experience from your
>   merchant cart to the payment flow.

This means you just have to create a profile once for your app. The profile can be used to place multiple payments. You don't need to necessarily delete it.